# Have Task Scheduler Run A Program From Program's Location

Tags: windows, script, scheduled-tasks

I've written up a .cmd script that I would like to run everyday at 7:30 AM.  Right now, if I run the task manually it's able to run all of the commands I put in there (some of which are auxiliary .cmd scripts) because the program launches from the parent script's location.  When testing to see the way Window's Task Scheduler runs scripts, the current directory variable comes up as system32 (where cmd.exe is located), so when my script tries to find any of the auxiliary scripts, it fails because they're not located in system32.

I understand that at the beginning of my parent script I can simply put:

```
cd PathToParentScript
```

But I would like to avoid that as I plan on giving this script to other peers and want to keep all of my configuration variables in one place (namely, one of my auxiliary scripts).

Is it possible to have Task Scheduler launch the script from that script's location as opposed to where cmd.exe is located?  If so, how would I do that?

I have Windows 10.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, why did you decide to try a script-within-a-script scenario?  I am actually a big fan of Task Scheduler myself, but I also advocate relatively simple, stable tech solutions.  As a result, I would probably shy away from *"script inception"* like that.

Comment: No problem at all!  I actually really new to scripting, a coworker of mine showed me that a way that I could store my variables and easily call them would be to have a bunch of SET commands in another script that I then call in the parent script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configure your script to switch to the current location of the actual script by adding the following command at the beginning:

```
CD /d %~dp0
```

Which will expand to:

```
CD /d drive:path_of script
```

**Note:** The `/D` parameter enables CD to switch to the script's drive if different than the current drive.

The `%~dp0` syntax is a modification of the `%0` variable (which is the script file's name) by the `~dp` modifier, where  **d** is the drive and **p** is the path.

Answer (score 1):

The option where you set the action should also have a box labeled "Start in (optional)"  Set this to the folder you want your script to run in.